# how to select children documents in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

### The specific problem

I have three classes set up in a tree

Group Owner class:

```
class GroupOwner
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :origin_id,    type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :origin_type,  type: String

  embeds_many :groups
end
```

Group class:

```
class Group
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :slug,                type: String

  embedded_in :owner,         class_name: "GroupOwner"
  embeds_many :members,       class_name: "GroupMember"
end
```

Group Member class:

```
class GroupMember
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :origin_id,            type: BSON::ObjectId
  field :origin_type,          type: String

  embedded_in :group
end
```

And I want to do, is to grab all `Groups` meeting specified criteria, like all `Groups` with a given slug. I don't care which `GroupOwner` they're embedded in. I want them all. And when I have them, I want all `GroupMembers` inside them, that meet another set of criteria.

Since they don't exist outside the embedding, `Group.where()` obviously will not work. The furthest I've gone so far was:

`GroupOwner.elem_match(groups: {slug: 'friends'}).map(&:groups).flatten` but I hate this solution, since it uses Ruby to actually map the values. `Queryable.pluck` method is available in Mongoid, but it plucks the mongo documents so hard, they stop being objects in Ruby and become Hashes.

Even when I do map all the `Group` model objects, somehow this:

```
groups = GroupOwner.elem_match(groups: {slug: 'friends'}).map(&:groups).flatten
groups.elem_match(members: {origin_id: value})
```

...returns no elements at all. As if `elem_match` decided to stop working anywhere but in the root document.

### The very general problem

This is all an elaborate approach to a much more generic problem I seem to have:
Finding and/or deleting children documents that have a specific set of values.

i.e. – all that I'm trying to do, is to delete all `GroupMember` documents, which have a specific `origin_id`.

Comment: This is not a mongoid issue. Its related to how mongodb works. You cannot directly get the embedded documents, but only root documents, in your case GroupOwner. You have to first retrieve owners which have groups with specific criteria and then iterate on them to get the groups themselves.

Comment: Still, when I chose e.g. `GroupOwner.last.groups.where(<conditions>)` I not only choose and map a specific embedded array of hashes to an array of objects, I can also filter it. By this logic there needs to be a way to filter children's children and map them instead. It may not be available in mongoid, tho.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should place Group on its own collection. For what I've read on the mongodb docs this is the preferred way. You get easier queries, you don't have to get all groups and members when querying for a group owner and now you can easily change the group owner of a group. Although mongodb is schema free you define a schema on your app and there are no strict rules to follow like SQL normalisation so you need to think hard and carefully when choosing embedding vs association.

On mongodb you end up having replicated data because you don't have joins  so you might want to have group owner data inside your group document, for example the owner name.

Comment: MongoDB is *not* schema-free. It's clear that every document has a schema - the DB just doesn't enforce that all documents have to have the same schema nor that you have to declare the schema in advance.